# SSRS (SQL2014) - "Subscriptions cannot be created because the credentials used to run the report are not stored

Tags: reporting-services

After deploying my reports to the reporting server, I tried to add a subscription on one of my reports. It was not possible, and I got the error as described in this link.

http://www.kodyaz.com/reporting-services/subscriptions-cannot-be-created.aspx

All my reports use the same shared data source.

I applied the solution proposed in this link and it worked.

BUT Each time I deploy my reports (from SQL Server Data tools for Visual Studio 2013); the error comes back.

I tried to modify the properties of the shared datasource with SQL Server Data tools for Visual Studio 2013 before deploying;similarly to what is shown in the hyperlink, but in this case I am not able to access my reports anymore.

So, it seems that I could only modify the credentials "online" with my web browser; and not "offline" with SQL Server Data tools for Visual Studio 2013.

I remarked one difference between the "offline" and "online" properties of the shared data source : online, it is possible to check the box "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source". This checkbox does not exist in SQL Server Data tools for Visual Studio 2013.

This means : each time I redeploy the reports from SQL Server Data tools for Visual Studio 2013, I have to do the online manipulation on my web browser to get the subscriptions working; which is of course really annoying...

Does someone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by simply deploying the whole project and not only the shared data source.